# how to display saved fields with javascript when page is refreshed - Javascript Rails4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Javascript and your advise and help would be much appreciated.

- when the option `"only men"` or `"only women"` is selected the field `"quantity"` is displayed
- when the option `"both men & women"` is selected the fields `"quantity_men"` & `"quantity_women"` are displayed
- when i select the option `"both men & women"` and the fields `"quantity_men"` & `"quantity_women"` are displayed, when i write my qunatity and save and refresh the page the fields are hidden

> question

- with the quantity of men & women saved, how do i avoid the `class= specific_gender_quantity_content` from being hidden when i refresh the page.
- i tried the below code but i am unsure as i am new and your help would be much appreciated

views / events / _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.association :category_quantitygender, collection: CategoryQuantitygender.all, prompt: "select a category", label: "Quantity Gender Selection" %>
    <div class="general_gender_quantity_content">
        <%= f.input :quantity, placeholder: "quantity", label: false %>
    </div>
    <div class="specific_gender_quantity_content">
        <%= f.input :quantity_men, placeholder: "quantity men", label: "men" %>
        <%= f.input :quantity_women, placeholder: "quantity women", label: "women" %>
    </div>
```

assets / javascripts / events_form.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.general_gender_quantity_content').hide();
  $('.specific_gender_quantity_content').hide();
  $('#social_category_quantitygender_id').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
      $('.specific_gender_quantity_content').show();
      $('.general_gender_quantity_content').hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 1, 2) {
      $('.general_gender_quantity_content').show();
      $('.specific_gender_quantity_content').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can get the selected value and then show hide divs based on the selected value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var social_category_quantitygender_id = $('#social_category_quantitygender_id').val();
 if (social_category_quantitygender_id == 3) {
   $('.specific_gender_quantity_content').show();
 } else if (social_category_quantitygender_id == 1, 2) {
   $('.general_gender_quantity_content').show();
 } else {
   $('.general_gender_quantity_content').hide();
   $('.specific_gender_quantity_content').hide();
 }
```

});